# Deny all files, but index/default page with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to deny all files in a directory, but index.php (as being the default page).

This solutions works almost:

```
Deny from all
<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

The only problem: 'upload/index.php' is now accessable, but '/upload/' isn't. How can I allow the default page with htaccess?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is, as you may have figured it out, that you're denying all the stuff, then allow the URI 'index.php', but not the URI '/' -- even though the '/' gets redirected to the index.php behind the scenes, it's still a different URI, and thus it should be allowed too.

The easiest way to do it is using the [FilesMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch) directive, like this:

```
order allow,deny
<FilesMatch "^(index\.php)?$">
    allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

The regex `^(index\.php)?$` means "index.php or nothing".

Answer (score 0):

You could try using mod_rewrite, replace what you have with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index.php)?$
RewriteRul ^ - [L,F]
```