# Apache .htaccess - Block all URLs with ".php" but not "index.php"

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I like to block all ".php" requests for my site except the "index.php" how can I achieve this with .htacess and the rewrite mod?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*(.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Your solution is probably here : [Deny all files, but index/default page with htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12115091/4973076)

Comment: Or possibly there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865780/mod-rewrite-exception-for-a-specific-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negated condition patter in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ - [F,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this for years and it works perfectly. You can add multiple files to allow list separated by |

```
#PROTECT FILES
<Files *.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Files>

#ALLOW FILES
<FilesMatch index.php|captcha.php>
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```